# Creating an environment variable with the path of chrome

Tags: ruby, selenium, heroku, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-headless

I am trying to follow the steps of the following StackOverflow answer:

[Running ChromeDriver with Python selenium on Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41059144/running-chromedriver-with-python-selenium-on-heroku?rq=1)

But I can't figure out how to do this part.

**Question**

How do I create an environment variable `GOOGLE_CHROME_BIN`, with the path of chrome on heroku: `/app/.apt/usr/bin/google-chrome` and an environment variable called `CHROMEDRIVER_PATH` with the path of chromedriver on heroku: `/app/.chromedriver/bin/chromedriver`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Heroku CLI for your app:

```
$ heroku config:set GOOGLE_CHROME_BIN=/app/.apt/usr/bin/google-chrome
$ heroku config:set CHROMEDRIVER_PATH=/app/.chromedriver/bin/chromedriver
```

Or you can do this by editing the config vars on your app’s settings tab on Dashboard