# How to set path to chromedriver in heroku chromedriver buildpack

Tags: python, selenium, heroku, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to set up selenium on heroku. I've been looking at [Running ChromeDriver with Python selenium on Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41059144/running-chromedriver-with-python-selenium-on-heroku) for some help. Based on this I installed the 2 buildbacks listed. I'm using cedar-14 since the 16 stack is not supported.

When I run:

```
$ heroku buildpacks
===  Buildpack URLs
1. heroku/python
2. https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-chromedriver
3. https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-xvfb-google-chrome
```

In any case I'm trying to use

```
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-chromedriver/tree/master/bin
```

My code contains:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
CHROMEDRIVER_PATH = os.getenv('$HOME') or basedir+'/chromedriver.exe'
FLASK_CONFIG = os.getenv('FLASK_CONFIG')

if FLASK_CONFIG and FLASK_CONFIG == "production":
    options.binary_location = os.getenv('$GOOGLE_CHROME_SHIM')
    options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
    options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=CHROMEDRIVER_PATH, options=options)
```

This code works fine locally, but on heroku:

```
 driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=CHROMEDRIVER_PATH, options=options)

2018-02-10T16:37:32.121783+00:00 app[web.1]: selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable may have wrong permissions. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home
```

How do I set the path to the chromedriver in the buildpack?

Answer (score 4):

Not sure about the heroku-buildpack-xvfb-google-chrome buildpack; I'm using heroku/google-chrome

You can use this snippet to configure your definition

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

def load_chrome_driver(proxy):

      options = Options()

      options.binary_location = os.environ.get('GOOGLE_CHROME_BIN')

      options.add_argument('--headless')
      options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
      options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
      options.add_argument('--remote-debugging-port=9222')
      options.add_argument('--proxy-server='+proxy)

      return webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=str(os.environ.get('CHROMEDRIVER_PATH')), chrome_options=options)
```

I'm using proxies, but you can probably avoid that. Set the following path using `heroku config:set` command

`CHROMEDRIVER_PATH=/app/.chromedriver/bin/chromedriver` and
`GOOGLE_CHROME_BIN=/app/.apt/usr/bin/google-chrome`

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
  options = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new
  Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Service.driver_path = '/app/.chromedriver/bin/chromedriver'
  chrome_bin_path = ENV.fetch('GOOGLE_CHROME_SHIM', nil)

  if chrome_bin_path
    options.binary = chrome_bin_path if chrome_bin_path
    options.add_argument '--no-sandbox'
    options.add_argument '--window-size=1200x600'
    options.add_argument '--headless'
    options.add_argument '--disable-gpu'
  end
  
  browser = Watir::Browser.new(:chrome, options:)
```