# Running Selenium+Chromedriver through a proxy?

Tags: python, selenium, heroku, proxy, selenium-chromedriver

I'm running Selenium (really [Splinter](https://splinter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)) in Python on a Heroku server. I need to run it through a proxy server, but most options for proxies seem to work only with Firefox, which can't run on Heroku.

I've been trying to use the QuotaGuard addon by just adding an argument to chrome options, but it only results in getting blank web pages. Here's the setup (using the chromedriver/Google Chrome buildbacks, which place the bin in GOOGLE_CHROME_SHIM):

```
chrome_bin = os.environ.get('GOOGLE_CHROME_SHIM', None)
opts = ChromeOptions()
opts.add_argument("proxy-server=SOME_URL")
opts.binary_location = chrome_bin
with Browser('chrome', executable_path="chromedriver", options=opts) as browser:
    # Do stuff
```

What's the best way to basically have it run through another IP address? Is there another way to do that that's not a proxy server?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41059144/running-chromedriver-with-python-selenium-on-heroku

Comment: I already have Chrome set up in the browser. The question is how to route the requests through a proxy server. I’ve tried using the chrome —proxy-server flag but it gives me blank pages, so I was wondering what other options there were.