# How to run RSelenium script in Heroku

Tags: r, selenium, heroku, selenium-chromedriver, rselenium

I've been struggling to run an R script on Heroku with RSelenium. I have other scripts running on the platform, but I can't make a Selenium server start. I'm trying it using the help I found
[here on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41059144/running-chromedriver-with-python-selenium-on-heroku). I have Google Chrome and ChromeDriver added to my Heroku slug. I managed to pull up the following code:

```
eCaps <- list(chromeOptions = list(args = c('--headless', '--disable-gpu', '--blink-settings=imagesEnabled=false',
                                           '--disable-dev-shm-usage', '--no-sandbox', '-Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=/app/.chromedriver/bin/chromedriver'),
                                   binary = Sys.getenv("GOOGLE_CHROME_BIN")))
remDr <- remoteDriver(
 browser = "chrome",
 extraCapabilities = eCaps
)

remDr$open()
```

where I have an environment variable `GOOGLE_CHROME_BIN` storing the path of the Chrome binary as `/app/.apt/usr/bin/google-chrome`.

When I run the script I'm getting the following error:

```
[1] "Connecting to remote server"
Error in checkError(res) : 
  Undefined error in httr call. httr output: Failed to connect to localhost port 4444: Connection refused
Calls: <Anonymous> -> queryRD -> checkError
```

Comment: I don't think the Heroku supports R Language. In the official web site there isn't the R icon. The answer that you found is about Python.

Comment: It doesn't support it officially, but there's a buildpack for R [here](https://github.com/virtualstaticvoid/heroku-buildpack-r) so you can run R scripts.